# Уведомление о добавлении в друзья

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы когда в базе появилась новая запись что один человек хочет добавить другого человека в друзья у того на странице появилось уведомление(Даже если он не перезагружает страницу).Пс как можно что бы на ajax Отправился потом ответ в базу о согласии или нет.Киньте какую нить идею по поводу этого,пример наводящий,заранее спасибо.

Comment: здесь нужен 1 скрипт, в нем запрос к базе, 5 строк на js(jquery) для реализации технологии ajax.

P.S. какой вопрос, такой ответ

за тебя ни кто делать не будет, покажи что сделал сам, и что не получилось

Comment: У любого пользователя, при загрузке страницы, по таймеру, будет выполняться ajax запрос, результатом которого будут нужные тебе данные.

Сия схема справедлива как для уведомления о добавлении в друзья, так и для уведомления о приеме, либо отказе заявки.

Вот очень кратко, хотите больше? Как уже писали выше - сделайте хоть что-то сами и вам помогут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы было без перезагрузки, надо загнать функцию проверки в setinterval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
      //здесь код запроса к php скрипту
      //допустим, что скрипт возвращает нам количество заявок в друзья N
      if(N > 0){
        //выводим сообщение
      }
    }, 2000);
});
```

2000 соответствует 2-м секундам